# Can `awk` sum a column over a specified number of lines

Tags: awk, numeric-data

I've reviewed the "Similar questions", and none seem to solve my problem:

I have a large CSV input file; each line in the file is an `x,y` data point. Here are a few lines for illustration, but please note that in general the data **are not** [monotonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function):

```
1.904E-10,2.1501E+00  
3.904E-10,2.1827E+00  
5.904E-10,2.1106E+00  
7.904E-10,2.2311E+00  
9.904E-10,2.2569E+00  
1.1904E-09,2.3006E+00
```

I need to create an output file that is smaller than the input file. The output file will contain ***no more than*** **one line** for every **N lines** in the input file. Each single line in the output file will be a `x,y` data point which is the *average* of the `x,y` values for **N lines** of the input file.

For example, if the total number of lines in the input file is 3,000, and **N=3**, the output file will contain ***no more than*** 1,000 lines. Using the data above to complete this example, the first 3 lines of data above would be replaced with a single line as follows:

x = (1.904E-10 + 3.904E-10 + 5.904E-10) / 3 = 3.904E-10

y = (2.1501E+00 + 2.1827E+00 + 2.1106E+00) / 3 = 2.1478E+00, or:

```
3.904E-10,2.1478E+00
```

for one line of the output file.

I've fiddled with this for a while, but haven't gotten it right. This is what I've been working with, but I can't see how to *iterate* the `NR` value to work through the entire file:

```
awk -F ',' 'NR == 1, NR == 3 {sumx += $1; avgx = sumx / 3; sumy += $2; avgy = sumy / 3} END {print avgx, avgy}' CB07-Small.csv
```

To complicate this a bit more, I need to "thin" my output file still further:

If the value of `avgy` (as calculated above) is ***close*** to the last value of `avgy` in the output file, I will not add this as a new data point to the output file. Instead I will calculate the next `avgx` & `avgy` values from the next **N lines** of the input file. ***"Close"*** should be defined as a percentage of the last value of `argy`. For example:

> if the current calculated value of `avgy` differs by less than 10% from the last value of `avgy` recorded in the output file, then do not write a new value to the output file.

<sub>see edit history</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here’s a generic variant:

```awk
BEGIN { OFS = FS = "," }

{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) sum[i] += $i
    count++
}

count % 3 == 0 {
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) $i = sum[i] / count
    delete sum
    count = 0
    if ($NF >= 1.1 * last || $NF <= 0.9 * last) {
        print
        last = $NF
    }
}


END {
    if (count > 0) {
        for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) $i = sum[i] / count
        if ($NF >= 1.1 * last || $NF <= 0.9 * last) print
    }
}
```

I’m assuming that left-overs should be handled in a similar fashion to blocks of *N* lines.

Comment: Looks awesome - thanks. A few questions to help me understand this:  `1.` What does `count % 3` do; i.e. purpose?   `2.` In an input file of say, 10 million lines, what is the largest array size possible; i.e. `sum[i]`?   `3.` The data I'll be processing will not be monotonically increasing; increase for a bit, then decrease for a bit. Will `$NF >= 1.1 * last` "capture" decreases?

Comment: 1. `count % 3` calculates `count` modulo 3, *i.e.* the remainder of `count` divided by 3. When that’s 0, `count` is an integer multiple of 3. 2. The size of the array depends on the number of fields per record (the number of columns); it doesn’t vary with the number of lines. 3. I implemented your spec, which says “if the current calculated value of `avgy` is less than **1.1** times the last value of `avgy` recorded in the output file, then do not write a new value to the output file”; by those terms, if the average decreases, it won’t be output again.

Comment: I apologize for my sloppy language. What I should have said is “if the current calculated value of `avgy` **differs by** less than **10% from** the last value of `avgy` recorded in the output file, then do not write a new value to the output file”. Maybe something like, `abs($NF - last)` ??

Comment: I assumed that, since the requirement was a quote, it came from somewhere else ;-). I’ve updated the answer to account for a 10% decrease too (AWK doesn’t have `abs()`, and while it would be trivial to write as a function, I just added the decrease as a disjunction).

Comment: Many thanks! The quote is actually original... quoted because I wanted to highlight it, and at the time, I thought it was "well written" :0  lol  I'll try this on my measurement files as soon as I am able, and let you know the results. FYI, this is all directed toward creation of a [PWL file](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspice-piecewise-linear-functions-for-voltage-current-sources.html) from my [oscilloscope measurements](https://imgur.com/a/JcRDZ7k) of [contact bounce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch#Contact_bounce); i.e. evaluating schemes for "de-bouncing".

Comment: If you’re trying to debounce, wouldn’t it be more effective to compare each value to a moving average, without resampling? And don’t you want to preserve the time domain, *i.e.* output a value in every cycle, either the recorded value or the last value? I’m wondering about the use of a percentage too — as a result, your debouncing “band” is proportional to the value, and you don’t debounce at all around 0...

Comment: I'm not sure - this is *my best guess*. The most important feature of the data is the frequency content. That led me to simply "cull" all the small changes. I need to get the data set from 10 million data points to about 5,000 data points. But I couldn't ask that question here - it's off-topic. I [posted this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65516932/how-to-thin-a-large-csv-file-to-extract-its-salient-features), but they closed as being opinion-based :)   Why don't you look at the SO question & if you still feel another approach is better, I'd enjoy discussing that.

Comment: And yes - my "percentage logic" is flawed. Something else I botched in my question: My idea was to use a percentage of the voltage swing (5 Volts in this case), but in my haste that was mis-stated. But after studying your code I decided I could make that change myself (I hate it when OPs keep changing their questions :)

Comment: Indeed, changing questions is rather annoying; I’m not suggesting we should answer all your questions in just this Q&A, and as you indicated by accepting this, I do think your initial question has been answered. The overall problem is an interesting one though ;-).

Comment: I agree - the logic in your code is spot on, and beyond answering this specific question, it will benefit other related tasks. FYI, I'm nominating it for the prestigious 'AWK of the Year' Award!  :)

Answer (score 1):

This checks for the line condition and the 10% rule. Keep in mind that the 10% rule has the side effect of increasing the check value linearly.

```
$ awk -F ',' '
  BEGIN{
    N=3; prev_y=0
  }
  {
    x+=$1;
    y+=$2;
    i++
  }
  NR%N==0 && (y/i) <= (prev_y)*1.1{ x=0; y=0; i=0 }
  NR%N==0 && (y/i) > (prev_y)*1.1{
    print x/i","y/i;
    prev_y=y/i; x=0; y=0; i=0
  }' file
```

Comment: +1 Thanks!  Yes - you're correct about the percentage; I'll need to look at that. Perhaps an absolute value would have been better?   ALSO:  I'm getting different results when I calculate my test file manually. Could you try your script against [my test file](https://github.com/seamusdemora/LTspiceRecipes/edit/main/CB07-Small.csv) & let me know what you get?

Comment: I'm getting -1.8096e-09,1.7561 -1.2096e-09,1.8014 -6.096e-10,1.8674 ... 1.5904e-09,2.2948

Comment: That's what I got also, but that can't be correct. Look at the first 2 `y` values: 1.7561 & 1.8014. The "disqualification range" for the 2nd point would have been 1.7561 +/- 0.1756, or  1.5805 to 1.9317.

Comment: Right, the updated `i` was not handled correctly. Should have been put into the previous value. I've updated the code. I now get: -1.8096e-09,1.7561 -4.096e-10,1.94391 7.904e-10,2.2311 and the leftover 1.2904e-09,2.29482

Comment: My spreadsheet says there are three data points in this set of 19: ( -1.809600E-09, 1.756100E+00 ) ; ( -9.600000E-12, 2.027767E+00 ); ( 1.190400E-09, 2.294833E+00 ). You're welcome to [try the spreadsheet](https://github.com/seamusdemora/LTspiceRecipes/blob/main/PWL-Check.xlsx); it may explain the logic better than my description.

Comment: I got the logic now. But this is not summarizing the data, it's actually losing data, because the averages are ONLY calculated on the 3 recent rows and only if the condition is met there its printed. The previous data is discarded. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes - discarding data is the primary objective in this case - see my comments to Stephen above.

Comment: Ok, I'll update the answer.